# iOS - Can't Display Downloaded Image

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata

I am downloaded images using the below code, but whenever I try to display them nothing shows up. I have tested the downloading of the images to my desktop from the app (in simulator) and all the images are created just fine. So I know they are being saved into the App's Documents directory.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Download Image Code:

```
-(void)saveThumbnails:(NSMutableArray *)thumbnails{
    for(NSNumber *videoID in thumbnails){
        // Get an image from the URL below
        NSURL *thumbnailURL = [self generateThumbnailURL:[videoID intValue]];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thumbnailURL]];

        NSLog(@"%f,%f",image.size.width,image.size.height);

        // Let's save the file into Document folder.
        // You can also change this to your desktop for testing. (e.g. /Users/kiichi/Desktop/)
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);//Find Application's Document Directory
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DownloadedThumbnails"];
//        NSString *dataPath = @"/Users/macminidemo/Desktop/gt";//DEBUG SAVING IMAGE BY SAVING TO DESKTOP FOLDER

        //Check if Sub-directory exists, if not, try to create it
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]){
            NSError* error;
            if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error]){
                NSLog(@"New Folder Created!");
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"[%@] ERROR: attempting to write create new directory", [self class]);
                NSAssert( FALSE, @"Failed to create directory maybe out of disk space?");
            }
        }
        NSArray *splitFilename = [[self generateThumbnailFilename:[videoID intValue]] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];//Break Filename Extension Off (not always PNGs)
        NSString *subString = [splitFilename objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *formattedFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@~ipad.png",subString];
        NSString *localFilePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:formattedFilename];
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [imageData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"Image: %@ Saved!",formattedFilename);
    }
}
```

Display Image Code:

```
if(currentVideo.thumbnail!=(id)[NSNull null] || ![currentVideo.thumbnail isEqualToString:@"missing_image.png"]){
    NSArray *splitFilename = [currentVideo.thumbnail componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];//Break Filename Extension Off (not always PNGs)
    NSString *subString = [splitFilename objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *formattedFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@~ipad.png",subString];

    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:formattedFilename];

    NSLog(@"Image Name: %@",formattedFilename);
    [videoThumbnail setImage:thumbnailImage];
    [buttonVideo addSubview:videoThumbnail];
}else{
    UIImage *thumbnailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video-details-thumbnail"];
    [videoThumbnail setImage:thumbnailImage];
    [buttonVideo addSubview:videoThumbnail];
}
```

*And there are no issues displaying the buttonVideo or anything like that. I have tested just setting a test image and that one display just fine (i.e. the "else" statement when run individually works just fine using the default thumbnail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `imageNamed` says that it works with files that are in the app's main **bundle**.  This suggests to me that it's only appropriate for images that are supplied as in-app resources.  Try `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to get at the content of the documents directory.

Comment: Ahhh. Genius! Yeah I kept trying to use [UIImage imageWithData:] and didnt realize there was a way to use the actual file.